# Implication becomes associative, in the category of strings of proven-true statements.

Tags: logic, category-theory, formal-languages

Consider the category of strings over some alphabet $\Sigma$, where each string is a reasonable representation (in some human language) of a proposition that has been proven true, or is axiomatized to be true, or thirdly is asserted to be true in preparation for a proof.  For example you might see "Let $G$ be a group." as a string, but then there's also "Let $H$ be a group." and so on.   I'm looking at this from a string parsing perspective, is why.

Anyway, draw an arrow between any two strings such that one implies the other (in whatever chosen language).  If $A \implies B$ then there is an arrow from $A$ to $B$ in the category, where $A, B$ are strings.

> This is indeed a category, correct?

Reason is because all the statement strings are assumed to be true.

Comment: If all statements in the category are 'true' and your morphisms are logical implication, then every statement has a unique morphism to every other statement. it's like a complete graph. I don't see why this wouldn't be a category

Comment: @JackCrawford Remember, though I don't know how to express it formally, for example, *$G$ is a group* does not imply necc. that $1 \in \Bbb{N}$ for instance, in the category.  Only "related" things are connected.   Thus it is probably a subcategory of the complete truth category.

Comment: @JackCrawford the two statements have to directly involve an common object or definition.  By directly, I mean it's in the strings themselves.  So, "Let $G$ be an abelian group" $\implies$ "$G$ is a group."  Each both involve more than at least one object or definition.  Each involves "group" and "$G$".  It's neat, because that's how I do math anyway, connecting statements which are strings, which represent concepts in my head.

Comment: Doesn't a statement $P$ being true mean that there is a morphism (say, $f:\mathrm{True}\to P$) from your terminal object 'True' back to it? and since 'True' is terminal, every other statement $Q$ has a morphism $g:Q \to \mathrm{True}$ to 'True': you should get a morphism from any statement $Q$ to any other statement $P$ by $f\circ g$ composing these two, right?

Comment: @JackCrawford see my last comment.  And I'll draw a picture why this is interesting, and edit the post.

Comment: @JackCrawford I don't think there would be an arrow coming from $\text{True}$, since for one, it's not a sentence.  The objects have to be English statements (say, or complete statements in another language).

Comment: I mean, I understand why you are suggesting that the statements should have something in common intuitively, but is it not still true as I said that a statement 'being true' *means* essentially that there exists a morphism $f:\mathrm{True}\to P$? What else does it mean for the statement to 'be true'?

Comment: When I say '$\mathrm{True}$' I mean the isomorphism class of things that are tautologically, trivially true. I don't know; make it the statement "True things are true" if you really need it to be a sentence. Is there not such an $f$ as I described, and if not, what else does it mean to say that the statement 'is true'?

Comment: @JackCrawford I'm not sure, but that's trivial with regards to the intuitition behind this.  Think about it this way, in what math book or software is the set of false statements faitfully represented, if at all?  It's not as that would not be doing math.  Math is solely concernced with the true statements.  Therefore, trivialize falseness and modulo it out.  The purpose of this is for thinking about propositions as strings, for the sake of coding something.

Comment: @JackCrawford No good math book would ever make a theorem that says *"True things are true" and that's interesting.*  So for lack of a better description, the objects "try to be interesting".  Remember, I'm thinking of representation of math knowledge, and not concerned with trivialities about it.  Those can be coded around or whatever...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98256/discussion-between-shine-on-you-crazy-diamond-and-jack-crawford).

Comment: The question is what exactly the definition of your morphisms is. All true statements imply each other, as Jack says.

Comment: I came to a conclusion in the chat room, that an arrow is drawn from $A$ to $B$ if and only if $A \implies B$ and their exists at least one object or definition in common to both the strings $A, B$.  So for instance "group" would be a definition directly in common with "Let $G$ be a group" =: $A$ and $B$ := "Let $G$ be an abelian group".  But so too would object "$G$" be shared between them.  So as long as the set of shared ideas is not empty, then you can draw an arrow when one implies the other.  This is well-defined since the shared objects can go down to one and stay there possibly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you handle all the details correctly, then yes, constructions like this produce categories (more specifically [preorders](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/preorder)), basically because implication is transitive ("hypothetical syllogism"): if $A \Rightarrow B$ and $B \Rightarrow C$ then $A \Rightarrow C$.

There's some work to do in handling all the details correctly. As in the comments, depending on exactly what kind of statements you're working with you may end up with a very small category (up to equivalence), which may only have one isomorphism class of object (all the true statements) or two isomorphism classes of objects (all the true statements, all the false statements). For more interesting variations see, for example, [Heyting algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Heyting+algebra) and [this blog post](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2013/12/10/how-to-invent-intuitionistic-logic/).

Here's one possible variation which sounds like it's along the lines of what you want. Choose a [first-order theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_first-order_theories) $T$, say [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms#First-order_theory_of_arithmetic) or the theory of groups, and consider the collection $F_T$ all [well-formed formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-formed_formula) in that theory. For Peano arithmetic this will be statements like "for all positive integers $a, b$, it's the case that $a + b = b + a$" and for group theory this will be statements like "for all elements $g$ it's the case that $g \cdot g^{-1} = g^{-1} \cdot g = e$" ($g$ belongs to an implicit background group $G$).

$F_T$ forms quite an interesting preorder under implication in general. There are at least two isomorphism classes of objects, namely the provably true and the provably false statements, which are precisely the statements true resp. false in all models of the theory $T$ (by the [completeness theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_completeness_theorem)). But in general there may be statements in $F_T$ which are neither provably true nor provably false, which (again by the completeness theorem) are precisely the statements which are true in some models but false in others. For Peano arithmetic such statements exist by the [incompleteness theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_incompleteness_theorems), and for groups one can very explicitly exhibit examples such as "$\forall g, g^2 = e$." These statements can have interesting implication relations with each other, which are reflected in the embedding of $F_T$ into the poset of subsets of the set of models of $T$ given by sending a statement in $F_T$ to the set of all models in which it's true. (Strictly speaking, the collection of models of $T$ may be too large to form a set, so I should say "subclass of the class of all models..." or something awkward like that.)

Comment: Also, I don't understand your title at all.

Comment: It's because I naturally expected $\implies$ to be associative, but it's not.  -_-  However, doing this with string representations of true statements "gets around" that.